# html2pdf my table gets cut between two pages

Tags: html2pdf

I ask for your help regarding the cutting of a table in html2pdf.
After the regeneration of my script, at the end of the page, my table is split into 2 with a new table header... is it possible to keep the table in a single block even if it means moving it to the second page please?

I am using the latest version of html2pdf

```
<?php
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/config.php");
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/vendor/autoload.php");

use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\Html2PdfException;
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\ExceptionFormatter;

try {
    ob_start();
    include dirname(__FILE__).'/imprimer/imprimer.php';
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    $html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'fr');
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($content);
    $html2pdf->output('Tableau de suivi - SIVOP CI - '.date("Y-m-d").'.pdf');
} catch (Html2PdfException $e) {
    $html2pdf->clean();
    $formatter = new ExceptionFormatter($e);
    echo $formatter->getHtmlMessage();
}
?>
```

print.php

```
<?php
$valeur = "Produit";

try{
$query = "SELECT * FROM $TABLE_PROJET WHERE statut = :valeur ORDER BY nature DESC, marque ASC, libelle ASC";
$stats = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stats ->execute(['valeur' => $valeur]);
while($data = $stats->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$hash       = $data["hash"];
$code       = $data["code"];
if($code != null) {$code = "<b>".$code."</b>&nbsp;|&nbsp;";} else {$code = null;}
$date       = "<span class='small'>".strftime("%d-%m-%Y", strtotime($data["date"]))."</span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;";
$marque     = "<b>".$data["marque"]."</b>&nbsp;»&nbsp;";
$libelle    = "<b>".$data["libelle"]."</b>";
?>

<table class="table-block" width="100%" name="long-table" style="margin-bottom:10px; padding:0; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <thead><tr style="<?=$tableau_04?>"><td colspan="3"><?=$date.$code.$marque.$libelle?></td></tr></thead>
    <tbody style="border-color: #212529;">
<?php require("imprimer/tableau.php"); ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<?php }}catch(PDOException $e){echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>".$e->getMessage()."</div>";} ?>
```

Thank you for your help
[image: My table]

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: A possible solution is to add a (manual) page break *before* the table, so it moves to a separate page

Comment: Please share the **generated** HTML markup that is neccessary to reproduce the problem